# Use the UNPIVOT function on a table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do a simple `UNPIVOT` to take data like this...

```
PLANT_CODE,PARTNO,ITEM_CODE,PROPERTY,LS,T,US
1002,400000000433009800,Widget 1,Stack height,11,12,13
```

And place it into data like this...

```
PLANT_CODE,PARTNO,ITEM_CODE,PROPERTY,SpecType,SpecValue
1002,400000000433009800,Widget 1,Stack height,LS,11
1002,400000000433009800,Widget 1,Stack height,T,12
1002,400000000433009800,Widget 1,Stack height,US,13
```

I am familiar with the `PIVOT` function but this is my first time doing using the `unpivot` command. If someone can provide an example (even with my data), that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What's wrong with the UNPIVOT examples you find when you google?

Comment: If you tried something and meet some problem you can show us, we will be glad to help you :)

Comment: My simple brain can't seem to wrap my mind around the UNPIVOT function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a big fan of using `apply` for this purpose:

```
select t.PLANT_CODE, t.PARTNO, t.ITEM_CODE, t.PROPERTY,
       v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('LS', LS), ('T', T), ('US', US)) v(SpecType, SpecValue);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a7920a3a567e5dbb4222c4c39efb2c06) is a db<>fiddle.

I consider this code simpler (although one could perhaps disagree).  More importantly, this introduces lateral joins (what the `apply` keyword does).  These are very powerful and unpivoting is just the tip of the iceberg -- and a good introduction to them.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the samples
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

```
DECLARE @t table 
(
    PLANT_CODE varchar(50)
    ,PARTNO varchar(50)
    ,ITEM_CODE varchar(50)
    ,PROPERTY varchar(50)
    ,LS varchar(50)
    ,T varchar(50)
    ,US varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT 
    '1002','400000000433 009800','Widget 1','Stack height','11','12','13'

SELECT 
    PLANT_CODE,PARTNO, ITEM_CODE, PROPERTY, SpecType, SpecValue
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        PLANT_CODE,PARTNO,ITEM_CODE,PROPERTY,LS, T, US
    FROM @t
) pvt
UNPIVOT
    (
    SpecValue for  SpecType IN (LS, T, US)
    )
as unpvt
```